# SEVIS Fee Application F-1

Tags: usa

Good Morning,

I have just received my I-20 from a University in the United states. I have a Question i want to ask, i do see most folks on here talking about making payment for the SEVIS fee before the Visa interview, hence i wanted to ask if its compulsory to make the payment for the SEVIS fee before i attend a Visa interview. or can i make the payment after the Interview.

I am from Nigeria

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must pay the fee before the interview at the Embassy. [source](https://www.ice.gov/sevis/i901/faq)

The only cases when you do not need to pay the fee are:

- You paid the fee within 12 months for another student or exchange visitor visa, including if you were denied for the earlier visa (must be same category, and you might have to transfer the fee is the SEVIS ID has changed)
- You are applying for a dependent visa based on the applicant applying as a student of exchange visitor
- You are applying for a government-sponsored exchange programs, G-1, G-2, G-3, or G-7
- Fell out of status for a minor reason when in F, M, or J status.